# Counter example of Poincare's inequality.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, integrable-systems

Give an example of a sequence of function in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ to show that the Poincaré inequality does not hold on a general non-compact domain.

I tried to find the sequence in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that it is not belong to $L^2$ on unbounded domain in but its dirivative is in $L^2$ in that unbounded domain but this sequence has to vanish on the boundary.

Consider

$f(x)= \begin{cases}
        x^{-1/3} &\text{if}\,\, x\neq 0\\
        0 & \text{if}\,\, x = 0
    \end{cases}$ and $f'(x)= \begin{cases}
        -\dfrac{1}{3}x^{-4/3} &\text{if}\,\, x\neq 0\\
        0 & \text{if}\,\, x = 0
    \end{cases}$ on the domain $(1, \infty).$

$$\int_1^{\infty}x^{-2/3}dx=+\infty$$

but

$$\int_1^{\infty} -\dfrac{1}{3}[x^{-4/3}]^2dx=\dfrac{5}{9}.$$

It is easy to find an example that it is not integrable on unbounded domain but its dirivative is integrable in that unbounded domain. But the problem is in my example $f$ is not continuously differentiable at $0$ at not vanish on boundary.

So I have trouble to find the function belongs to $C^1(\mathbb{R}),$ counte-examples that I found only countinuously differentiable on limit domains not for $\mathbb{R}$ and the function should be vanish on the boundary.

I also saw a lot of the examples with $u(x) \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ with $u$ is even not continuous.

Could you provide me any idea?

Comment: What about $f \equiv 1$?

Comment: @user23571113 Please see my edited question. We need the condition $f=0$ on the boundary. I really sorry for my mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by "$f = 0$ on the boundary" if $f$ is supposed to be defined on $\mathbb{R}$? Do you mean $\lim\limits_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = 0$?

Comment: @user23571113 Yes, and $f(0)=0$  in my example because I consider the domain $(0; \infty).$

Comment: @user23571113 but for the counter-example, you only need a $C^1$ function and $f$ is vanish on the boundary of the unbounded domain $D$ you consider, it is not necessary to choose $D =\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Try convolving ur function with a mollifier  to make your function smooth and try to check the inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

Comment: Wouldn't any sequence of smooth compactly supported functions converging to $f=1$ also work here?

Comment: How about $\Large\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}}$?

Comment: @Balajisb Both of you refer to sequence Mollifier functions $\phi_n(x)=c_n e^{\dfrac{1}{n^2-x^2}}$, right?

Comment: @whpowell96 Both of you refer to sequence Mollifier functions $\phi_n(x)=c_n e^{\dfrac{1}{n^2-x^2}}$, right?

Comment: @user23571113 Thank you. I will check the integral, but I think it seems to be a complicated computation.

Comment: @Gonçalo You right. At first I consider the function on domain $(1, \infty)$ but I forgot the condition $f=0$ on the boundary so I changed the domain into (0, \infty) without checking clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example I gave in my last comment can be simplified a lot, you can just take
$$
\Large f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac14}}.
$$
It is not square integrable because we have
$$
\Large \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac12}} \geq \frac{1}{(2x^2)^{\frac12}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{x}
$$
for $x \geq 1$ and its derivative
$$
\Large f'(x) = -\frac{x}{2(1+x^2)^{\frac54}}
$$
is square integrable because
$$
\Large \frac{x^2}{4(1+x^2)^{\frac52}} \leq \frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^{\frac52}} \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For the first integral, are you considering the integral on the domain $(1, \infty)$, aren't you? So I think it does not satisfy the condition $f$ is vanish on the boundary since $f(1)=\dfrac{1}{2}\neq 0.$

Comment: @Lilili123 No the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ the entire time, I just use the interval $[1, \infty)$ for that specific estimate. The integral of $f^2$ over the real line is then divergent because even just the integral over $[1, \infty)$ is divergent (because of the estimate).

Comment: But the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{x}dx$ is indefinite.

Comment: Now I got your idea, so we have $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f^2dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}f^2dx \geq 2\int_{1}^{\infty}f^2dx \geq 2\int _{1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2 x}dx=+\infty.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.